# Which font has been used

Tags: fonts, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture)

Which font ist used in the following document?

http://www.math.helsinki.fi/logic/people/jouko.vaananen/shortcourse.pdf

[image: excerpt from the mentioned document]

Comment: Ah, this done in word, I'm sorry.

Comment: or off-topic because it's not a LaTeX document.

Comment: The main font is a form of Times (Linotype Times, as can be seen from the digit 5). The math symbols are from Adobe Symbol. Very poor typography; the spacing in math formulas is mostly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The font used is Times New Roman. You can look at the used fonts in Adobe Reader, under Properties (or something like that) -> Fonts. If you use Linux, you can use the tool `pdffonts`.